# open graph string linebreak using meta tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, line-breaks, meta

I am currently updating my page with facebook open graph meta tags so it get's a nice preview when pasting the url to facebook.
Sadly, the og:description property or any other property of type string seems to ignore linebreaks.
I've tried any known format for linebreaks like \n or <br> but none of them work.

Does anyone know the trick or is it just not possible to add linebreaks?

Thanks, McFarlane

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe Facebook, Twitter or any other content sharing sites will allow formatting data in meta tags. Your best chance is to study how many characters these sites use in each line of the preview and insert appropriate number of spaces to simulate line break. (If they ignore white spaces)